# ReCaptcha Incorrect Sol - perl

Tags: perl, cgi, md5, captcha

I've been working on a register form for a game I'm developing, everything works fine except the captcha. It keep's saying **incorrect sol** even though I am entering the answer correctly. I tried debugging using `Data::Dumper` and it seems like it keeps returning false every time.

http://s15.postimg.org/vy5kt6zaz/x_REuan_W.png

This is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Captcha::reCAPTCHA;
use Data::Dumper;

my $captcha = Captcha::reCAPTCHA->new();
my $html = CGI->new();
my $public_key = "6Ldbc9cSAAAAACYGs9FWEemI_A4Atx20sOtk6YA-";
my $private_key = "6Ldbc9cSAAAAAHs88TTzyytdrIlkbVx3h5x55t8j";

sub checkAndRegister {

    my $result = $captcha->check_answer($private_key, 
                                        $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}, 
                                        $html->param("recaptcha_challenge_field"), 
                                        $html->param("recaptcha_response_field")
                                    );

    print Dumper($result);

    if ($result->{is_valid}) {
        #do stuff here

    } else {

        die ($result->{error});

    }
}


sub output_form {
    print $captcha->get_html($public_key);
}
```

Help would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I've been trying for the past 2 hours, I'm unable to figure it out, I know I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure where.

Comment: "narrow down" here means remove as much code as possible while still exhibiting the problem; you haven't done that, and doing so is likely to find your problem quicker than anything else.

Comment: It works perfectly now. I tried what you told me to. Thank you @ysth that fixed it.

Comment: well, that's good.  changed my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this under mod_perl or similar, the $html used in checkAndRegister will be a separate variable from the $html used everywhere else after the first request; pass it into checkAndRegister to fix this.

If you enable warnings, you will see a "Variable ... will not stay shared" warning about this.  You can read about it [here](http://perl.apache.org/docs/general/perl_reference/perl_reference.html#my____Scoped_Variable_in_Nested_Subroutines).